# Make a creature face the direction it's moving in opengl

Tags: opengl, glut, jogl

Below to my spider.java class (though right now the spider is just a sphere and a stick)

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.gl2.GLUT;

import java.util.*;

public class Spider
{
  private int spider_object;
  private int texture;
  private float x, y, z; // position

  private float travel_speed;
  private float travel_dir_x;
  private float travel_dir_y;
  private float travel_dir_z;

  public Spider( float _x, float _y, float _z, 
          float _travel_speed)
  {
      x = _x;
      y = _y;
      z = _z;
      travel_speed = _travel_speed;


      travel_dir_x = 0.4f;
      travel_dir_y = 0.5f;
      travel_dir_z = 0.5f;
  }

  public void init( GL2 gl )
  {

    spider_object = gl.glGenLists(1);
    gl.glNewList( spider_object, GL2.GL_COMPILE );


    // create the spider
    GLUT glut = new GLUT();
    //glut.glutSolidSphere( 1, 10, 10 );
    glut.glutSolidCube(1);
    glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.2, 2, 10, 10);


    gl.glEndList();

  }



  public void update( GL2 gl )
  {
    translate();

  }

  public void translate()
  {
      x += travel_speed*travel_dir_x;
      y += travel_speed*travel_dir_y;
      z += travel_speed*travel_dir_z;

      if(x > 2 || x < -2)
          travel_dir_x = -travel_dir_x;
      if(y > 2 || y < -2)
          travel_dir_y = -travel_dir_y;
      if(z > 2 || z < -2)
          travel_dir_z = -travel_dir_z;

  }

  public void draw( GL2 gl )
  {
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glPushAttrib( GL2.GL_CURRENT_BIT );
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    gl.glRotatef( -90, 0, 1, 0 );
    gl.glScalef(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);


    if (travel_dir_x > 0)
        gl.glRotatef(-45, 0, 0, 0);    
    else
        gl.glRotatef(135, 0, 0, 0);

    if (travel_dir_y > 0)
        gl.glRotatef(-90, 0, 1, 0);    
    else
        gl.glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);

    gl.glColor3f( 0.85f, 0.55f, 0.20f); // Orange
    gl.glCallList( spider_object );
    gl.glPopAttrib();
    gl.glPopMatrix();
  }
```

}

My goal is to make the creature to turn around and continue moving whenever it hits a "wall" in a 4x4 tank. The code snippets below shows that when you hit the edge of x, y, or z wall, the creature will reverse its direction

```
      if(x > 2 || x < -2)
          travel_dir_x = -travel_dir_x;
      if(y > 2 || y < -2)
          travel_dir_y = -travel_dir_y;
      if(z > 2 || z < -2)
          travel_dir_z = -travel_dir_z;
```

As of right now I think I figured out how to make it move left and right when it hits the "left" and "right" wall when the simulation first started. (Depending on the camera angle, it may not be left and right).

The following code is what **I think** makes the creature reverse direction and continues to move forward when hitting a wall. The following code is taken from the **draw()** function

```
    if (travel_dir_x > 0)
        gl.glRotatef(-45, 0, 0, 0);    
    else
        gl.glRotatef(135, 0, 0, 0);
```

If I mess with that chuck of code, my creature will disappear. I can however change the x, y, or z parameters to 1s and make it move at a different angle.

Is my understanding of the code above correct? How can I make it so that when the creature begins to move in a 3-D direction, it will look at that specific combination of x, y, and z as oppose to just look "left" and look "right" ??

Comment: It's probably easier to just have a variable holding the angles at which your model is displayed, and modify them whenever it changes direction, rather than do the tests at each rendering.

Comment: use [`angle = atan2(velocity.y, velocity.x)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Illustrations)

Comment: Just as a side note, using display lists is a bad idea, they are badly implemented in numerous drivers even in outdated drivers. When your spider becomes more complicated, use a vertex array, a compiled vertex array or preferably a static vertex buffer object to store its mesh.